# Получение подстрок по регулярному выражению с сохранением разделителя

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, kotlin, split

Здравствуйте. Есть регулярное выражение и строка, в которой содержится несколько подходящих последовательностей и какие-то символы до следующего совпадения. Необходимо получить эти строки. Подробнее на картинке:
[image: то, что необходимо получить]

Можно было бы использовать split("\b((\p{L})|\d+){1,2}\p{P}+".toRegex()), но мы не получаем в строках то, по чему делим, что не подходит.

Прошу совета)

Comment: Может, `"строка".split(Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9]+[)]"))`? Вашу регулярку можно поправить как `"\\b[\\p{L}\\d]{1,2}\\p{P}+"`.

Comment: так ведь разделители (цифры и знак пунктуации) все равно не останутся в итоговых строках?
А задача сохранить разделители в начале строки

Comment: Т.е. надо, чтобы остались? Тогда `"строка".split(Regex("(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]+[)])"))`. Или ваше `"(?=\\b[\\p{L}\\d]{1,2}\\p{P}+)"`.

Comment: отлично, все работает. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы разделители после разбиения текста остались в начале каждого элемента полученного массива, поместите ваше выражение в блок предварительного просмотра вперёд (`(?=...)`):

```
"строка".split(Regex("(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]+[)])"))
```

Или ваше:

```
"строка".split(Regex("(?=\\b[\\p{L}\\d]{1,2}\\p{P}+)"))
```

Блоки предварительного просмотра не помещают текст в буфер совпадения, совпадение остается неизменным при поиске шаблона блока, а когда блок заканчивает работу, возвращается значение true (продолжаем дальше) или false (стоп, нет совпадения).